# How to loop test cases in Katalon Studio?

Tags: android, testing, appium, katalon-studio

I have some 5 Test cases and I want them to keep running for 5-6 times repeatedly. How can I do that? Please help. 
For Profiling Purposes I want them to keep on running.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Test Suite listing the 5 Test Cases, then move to the Script tab and in the @SetUp method, set the true to false and add a line of a For loop. Not quite sure what you mean by "keep on running", but maybe instead of a For loop, you can insert a While loop. Both For loop or While loop are explained [here] (https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/common-condition-control-statements/)

Answer (score 1):

If the test cases can be executed independently of one another, you could do something like (using Groovy):

```
5.times {

    Mobile.callTestCase(findTestCase("Test Case 01"), [:])
    Mobile.callTestCase(findTestCase("Test Case 02"), [:])
    Mobile.callTestCase(findTestCase("Test Case 03"), [:])
    Mobile.callTestCase(findTestCase("Test Case 04"), [:])
    Mobile.callTestCase(findTestCase("Test Case 05"), [:])

}
```

See also https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Call+test+case.